# Android app with Phonegap won't load header image

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova, mobile

Making an android app with Phonegap. I want to have an image in the header.

For this I use CSS:

```
<style>
.center-wrapper span {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.center-wrapper img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
</style>
```

And then the header code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone"   >

<header data-role="header" class="ui-bar">


   <div class="center-wrapper">
    <img width="35" height="35" alt="Header" 
         src="ikon.png" /> 
      <span>TITEL</span>

  </div>
```

It works fine in IE and Chrome but the image won't load in my phone. Other images I have added within a table is loading correctly. Any ideas of what might be wrong?¨

Thanks.

Comment: you may try using <img width="35px" height="35px" alt="Header" 
         src="ikon.png" /> because as far as i know you must add % or px values in height and width